# What exactly is meant by 光彩照人？

Tags: meaning

It is not easy being a man in China, you need to have a lot of qualities!（I'll never qualify!)

男人要有责任心、为人正直、宽容、刚毅，不背叛朋友; 男人要上进，有报复，有魄力； 男人要谦虚，诚实，大方；男人要有修养，心胸开阔，处境艰难而不退缩，面对打击而不脆弱；男人是生活中的榜样，家庭的靠山，社会的支柱。总之，男人要顶天立地，光彩照人，要有男人的气概。

‘光彩照人’的意思呢？

Comment: 37 samples at jukuu:1:outshine (others),2:look radiant,... 37: shine brightly

Answer (score 5):

光彩照人
Shine; Brilliant; Radiant

---

[用以形容人或事物十分美好，令人注目、敬仰。](http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%89%E5%BD%A9%E7%85%A7%E4%BA%BA)
used to describe people or things are very beautiful, and make others impressive and respected.

---

[形容人外表亮麗或事物色彩鮮明，十分美好](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/clk/search/%E5%85%89%E5%BD%A9%E7%85%A7%E4%BA%BA/141468/238478)
Describe a person's appearance bright or things are bright and very beautiful.

---

[光彩照人 coloured and dazzling](http://tw.websaru.com/%E5%85%89%E5%BD%A9%E7%85%A7%E4%BA%BA.html)

a. 公主光彩照人地穿著一身雪白的新禮服來了。
The princess arrived, resplendent in a new white dress.

b. 阿勒頗的阿拉姆瑣瓦，他們講著一個關於前人哈卡姆•伊茲拉•哈馬威的傳說。這個故事說的是使他在非猶太人心目中光彩照人，在東方所有城市中名聲鵲起的某一功績。
In aram zova in aleppo they tell a tale about hakham ezra hamawi of blessed memory concerning a deed which exalted him in the eyes of the gentiles and won him a name in all the cities of the east.

---

[光彩照人 Radiant](http://www.iciba.com/%E5%85%89%E5%BD%A9%E7%85%A7%E4%BA%BA)

1. He is sparkling and versatile in front of the camera.
   镜头前的他光彩照人，多才多艺。
2. He glimpsed Sonia, resplendent in a red dress.
   他瞥了索尼亚一眼，见她一身红衣，光彩照人。
3. She glittered at the elegant table.
   她坐在典雅的桌子旁边显得光彩照人.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase「光彩照人」is related to two better known phrases:

> 1. 「光彩奪目」

「光彩」means: 'light and color'

「奪目」means: 'blinding/ dazzling'

「光彩奪目」 means : 「blindingly brilliant (of light and color) 」

It can be used literally to describe objects like diamonds and gems.

For example, 「這鑽石光彩奪目」(this diamond is blindingly brilliant )

Or metaphorically describe a person's brilliance.

For example: 「她的演出光彩奪目」(her performance is blindingly brilliant) - *comparing a person's brilliance to a gem's.*

- 「她的**光彩**」= 'her **brilliance**'

> 2. 「明艷照人」

「明艷」means 'radiant beauty'

「照人」means 'shining (upon people)'

「明艷照人」means ' radiant beauty shines'

> 「**光彩照人**」means ' **radiating brilliance; brilliance shines**'

Comment: 这样翻译好不好？ 男人要光彩照人：a man must be a shining example for others

Comment: 不好. " 男人要光彩照人" Should  be translated as " A man need to shine"